# How to bookmark pushState

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, history, pushstate

Please, can anyone guide me with this pushState code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Also, it cannot be bookmarkable. Why?

Thank you!

```
$(function(){
    if (Modernizr.history) {
        wrap = $('#wrap');
        $('a').click(function(event){
           url = $(this).attr('href');
           wrap.load(url + ' #main', function() {
               title = $('#main').find('h1').text();
               $('head').find('title').text(title);
               history.pushState(null, title, url);
           });
       event.preventDefault();
       });
   }
});
```